# sqlite3 DB doesn't use index unless vacuumed

Tags: indexing, sqlite, vacuum

Performing VACUUM on my DB significantly improves query performance. While trying to determine why this is, I found that sqlite3 isn't using the index on the DB in its original state, just a generic SEARCH TABLE.

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN TABLE data    <--- no Index
|--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

After performing VACUUM, the QUERY PLAN shows a SEARCH USING INDEX as it should

```
    QUERY PLAN
|--SEARCH TABLE data USING INDEX index_name (name=?)
|--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

How can I determine why the index isn't being used before the vacuum operation?

I have the explain results as well, but I'm not sure they'd be useful. They are clearly different (original, non-vacuumed result performs a Rewind/Loop where the vacuumed DB OpenRead's the index)

Thank you,

Comment: I think you should show us the query and the table(s) definition.

Comment: Not sure that I can (proprietary). What do you want to see specifically?

Comment: I need to see the query and table so I can try to figure out why the index is sometimes being used.  Maybe the optimizer views the index as a borderline case and, e.g., doing a vacuum affects correlation.